# Android Room and kotlin: Adding a conditional AND to a query (like a filter)

Tags: kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to create a query that returns the number of rows from a table based on the passed in ID and an array of boolean values that acts as an extra filter. As for now I add the filter using a vararg boolean, but this isn't optimal. Is there some other way to add this conditional functionality, that would make better sense?

Here's my query-method:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tasks WHERE id = :id AND deleted IN (:filterDeleted)")
abstract fun countTasksById(id: String, vararg filterDeleted: Boolean = booleanArrayOf(false, true)): Int
```

And here's how it's used:

```
@Test
fun shouldCountOnlyDeleted() {
    insertTestData(appDatabase)
    val deleted = TEST_TASKS.take(5)
    repository.softDeleteAll(deleted)
    val nonDeleted = TEST_TASKS.filterNot { it in deleted }

    deletedStudies.forEach {
        assertThat(repository.countTasks(it.id, true), `is`(1))
    }

    nonDeleted.forEach {
        assertThat(repository.countTasks(it.id, true), `is`(0))
    }
}

@Test
fun shouldCountBothDeletedAndNonDeleted() {
    insertTestData(appDatabase)
    val deleted = TEST_TASKS.take(5)
    repository.softDeleteAll(deleted)
    val nonDeleted = TEST_TASKS.filterNot { it in deleted }

    deletedStudies.forEach {
        assertThat(repository.countTasks(it.id, false, true), `is`(1))
    }
    nonDeleted.forEach {
        assertThat(repository.countTasks(it.id, false, true), `is`(1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@Delete
 public void deleteTasks(Task... tasks)
```

See: [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Delete)

Comment: I only do soft deletes. Meaning that I add a flag to a row when it should be deleted. The deletion doesn't happen until a synchronization happens with the backend.